# Looking for SmallChess source code?

Tags: engines, software, programming

I'm currently looking for this chess engine: http://www.smallchess.com/ but the link to access it is dead.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for SmallChess is not available as it is closed source. The link for the source code is for SmallFish.

If you still want the source code you might have to wait, as neither does Google have that page cached nor does The Wayback Machine.